# How to disable button in parent template while in child route in Ember?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm creating a simple user CRUD page (based on: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/11/07/an-in-depth-introduction-to-ember-js/) that allows editing, creation and deletion of users. After adding the editing functionality, I noticed that Edit button doesn't get disabled or removed during editing, and I wanted to add this functionality.

However I can't seem to come up with the solution because the edit button is in the parent template (`user` template, and I am in `user.edit`)

The closest I've got is by setting a property `editMode` in the `UserController` to true, and setting that property back in `save` action in `UserEditController` back to false. And it worked fine until I pressed the back button or changed the url.

I also tried other solutions like having `editMode` property that is true in the first controller, and false in the other, but the template doesn't seem to recognize this.

Here are my codes without the solutions above:

Router

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('users', function() {
        this.resource('user', { path: '/:user_id'}, function() {
            this.route('edit');
        });
        this.route('create');
    });
});
```

user

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="user">
  <button {{action "edit"}}>Edit</button>
  <div class="user-profile">
    <img {{bind-attr src="avatarUrl"}} alt="User's avatar" />
    <h2>{{name}}</h2>
    <span>{{email}}</span>
    <p>{{bio}}</p>
    <span>Created {{creationDate}}</span>
  </div>

  {{outlet}}
</script>
```

UserController

```
App.UserController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

    deleteMode: false,

    actions: {
        edit: function() {
            this.transitionToRoute('user.edit');
        }
    }
})
```

UserEditController

```
App.UserEditController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

    needs: ['user'],

    actions: {
        save: function(){
          var user = this.get('model');
          // this will tell Ember-Data to save/persist the new record
          user.save();

          // then transition to the current user
          this.transitionToRoute('user', user);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You could setup the controller properties in the activate/deactivate hook of each route (http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_activate). If you setup a http://emberjs.jsbin.com/, people would help u easier

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will setup an emberjs.jsbin.com for this issue.